# Heroku toolbelt fails update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, heroku

I'm trying to get Heroku toolbelt working and it's a total nightmare.  The install runs successfully, but when I run heroku update I get:

```
    $ heroku update 
         failed    
            !   undefined method `output_with_arrow' for #<Heroku::Command::Update:0x108da0120 @options={}, @args=[]>
```

I've tried everything, including uninstalling my heroku gem and removing the toolbelt via:

```
rm -rf /usr/loca/heroku
sudo rm /usr/bin/heroku
```

This is VERY frustrating. My environment is Mac OS 10.7 Lion and:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

$ which ruby
/Users/J/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby

$ heroku version
heroku-gem/2.19.2

$ which heroku
/usr/bin/heroku
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Heroku support finally helped me fix this.  Long story short, if you're having this issue, just run:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.heroku/client
```

Then reinstall the Heroku Toolbelt from http://toolbelt.heroku.com

If you want the long answer, here you go:

> There appear to be some edge cases where update ended up with some
>   incorrect data and it is somewhat more difficult to recover from this.
>   If you first delete the ~/.heroku/client directory and subsequently
>   run the installer you should end up with a working result.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku toolbelt is nice, but heroku_san offers all that and more. Maybe give it a shot?

https://github.com/fastestforward/heroku_san

Comment: Thanks, Chris, that looks pretty interesting, but Heroku is pushing this toolbelt pretty hard, and it's very frustrating that I can't get it to work.  I'm trying to do a db migration/promotion according to this:  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql, but nothing is working and I'm hoping/assuming it's because toolbelt won't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Dont have much fuss about about uninstalling and reinstalling it again.
Just Delete .heroku folder and it will start working fine...

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems installing Heroku on Windows. After installing and running at the command line for the first time, I got something like "Updating to 5.1.4-cc" and then simply 'panic:'. I couldn't find a '.heroku' folder, and after a lot of messing around, running heroku-cli.exe in {user}AppData\Local\heroku got it past that problem, then everything was good. Until this morning - one day later :) - when it tried updating again, to 5.1.5. I uninstalled everything, re-installed, same issue - but this time there was a '.heroku' folder, and deleting that got past the update issue.

Cheers