# rails/heroku migrating from gem to toolbelt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

I used to use the heroku gem with a project. Now that the toolbelt is out, I wanted to switch. I removed the gem from the Gemfile and I uninstalled it via gem uninstall heroku. I installed the heroku toolbelt with the pkg from heroku's website.

Now, everywhere on my system it seems that the new toolbelt is available when I do e.g.

```
 heroku version
```

But inside that one directory where I store my Rails Project, I get an error as it is still looking for the old heroku gem (that has now been uninstalled).

How do I link to the new toolbelt instead of the old gem inside that folder?

BTW: I've also created a new rvm gemset and it did not change the behaviour.

Comment: have you removed the gemfile.lock file as well, and the re-run `bundle`?

Comment: yes but it didn't help. any other ideas?

Comment: try doing an `ls -a` in your project directory to see if there are any hidden files that may be mucking up the works

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  Running into it myself...what a pain

Comment: I ended up setting up everything from scratch. Frustrating to hear probably but there didn't seem to be another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `~/.heroku/client` folder and reinstall toolbelt.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10988217/429758