# Upgraded Heroku from gem to toolbelt, but still old version

Tags: heroku, rubygems, heroku-toolbelt

Heroku recommends switching from the old gem to the new "Heroku Toolbelt":
https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/10/15/upgrading-to-the-heroku-toolbelt

I ran these commands successfully:

```
$ sudo gem uninstall heroku
$ sudo gem uninstall heroku --all
$ wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

Then I restarted my terminal, and... I still have the old version:

```
$ heroku version
heroku-gem/2.33.5 (x86_64-linux) ruby/1.9.3
$ heroku fork
 !    `fork` is not a heroku command.
$ which heroku
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/heroku
```

What did I forget?

---

Similar questions:

- [How do I replace the Heroku gem with Heroku Toolbelt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980298/how-do-i-replace-the-heroku-gem-with-heroku-toolbelt) but none of the answers work
- [Heroku toolbelt fails update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924779) and [rails/heroku migrating from gem to toolbelt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050678) but I have no `~/.heroku/client` folder

Comment: What is the output of `which heroku`?

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU: Added, thanks!

Comment: Try removing that file. `rm /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/heroku`.

Comment: Brutal but that did the trick, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you still have the gem installed in one of your rvm installations.
Try removing the gem without sudo:

`gem uninstall heroku`

The value of `which heroku` should not be in the `~/.rvm` folder, but `/usr/local`.